# Laravel - Lightgallery js is not initializing from blade file after importing package in app.js

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I am using [lightgallery](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/demos/inline/) in my project and installed the package with the [npm command](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/getting-started/#installation) and after that, I have imported package files(JS & CSS) in an app.js file like this:

```
import lightGallery from 'lightgallery';
import lgThumbnail from 'lightgallery/plugins/thumbnail';
import lgZoom from 'lightgallery/plugins/zoom';
import 'lightgallery/css/lightgallery.css';
import 'lightgallery/css/lg-zoom.css';
import 'lightgallery/css/lg-thumbnail.css';
```

Now I have created div in `<div id="inline-gallery-container" class="inline-gallery-container"></div>` in **dashboard.blade.php** file.

And after that, I have placed the below code in the **app.js** file:

```
const lgContainer = document.getElementById("inline-gallery-container");
        const inlineGallery = lightGallery(lgContainer, {
            container: lgContainer,
            dynamic: true,
            hash: false,
            closable: false,
            showMaximizeIcon: true,
            appendSubHtmlTo: ".lg-item",
            slideDelay: 400,
            plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail],
            dynamicEl: [
                {
                    src:
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542103749-8ef59b94f47e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80",
                    responsive:
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542103749-8ef59b94f47e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80",
                    thumb:
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542103749-8ef59b94f47e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80",
                    subHtml: `<div class="lightGallery-captions">
                            <h4>Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@dann">Dan</a></h4>
                            <p>Published on November 13, 2018</p>
                        </div>`
                },
                {
                    src:
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473876988266-ca0860a443b8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80",
                    responsive:
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473876988266-ca0860a443b8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=480&q=80 480, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473876988266-ca0860a443b8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80 800",
                    thumb:
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473876988266-ca0860a443b8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=240&q=80",
                    subHtml: `<div class="lightGallery-captions">
                            <h4>Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@kylepyt">Kyle Peyton</a></h4>
                            <p>Published on September 14, 2016</p>
                        </div>`
                },
            ],
            thumbWidth: 60,
            thumbHeight: "40px",
            thumbMargin: 4
        });
        inlineGallery.openGallery();
```

Now placing the above js code in the **app.js** file it's working properly but when I move code to the **dashboard.blade.php** file it giving me this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: lightGallery is not defined`

I am really don't know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to ensure you put the imports in the right place (eg. app.css / app.js). From my experience, if you want a function/class to be accessed globally, you need to assign it to the window in **app.js**.

You may need to copy the fonts to your public directory as well.

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import lightGallery from 'lightgallery';
import lgThumbnail from 'lightgallery/plugins/thumbnail'
import lgZoom from 'lightgallery/plugins/zoom'

window.lightGallery = lightGallery;
window.lgThumbnail = lgThumbnail;
window.lgZoom = lgThumbnail;
```

**resources/css/app.css**

```
@import '~lightgallery/css/lightgallery-bundle.css';
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.copyDirectory("node_modules/lightgallery/fonts", "public/fonts");
```